# rxjs multiple observable switch

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have 2 observables and I would like to achieve the following:

Get a value from *Observable1*, then ignore *Observable1* and only wait for a value from *Observable2* then the same, get a value from *Observable1* again and so on..

Is there a way to achieve this in rxjs? the Operation Decision Tree hasn't been useful.  I also played around with `switchMap()` but that can only do the first part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created you a custom operator (`toggleEmit`) that takes `N` observables and toggles between them.

```
const result$ = toggleEmit(source1$, source2$);
```

Implemented features:

- `N` observables can be given to the toggleEmit operator
- Observables will be emitted one by one and start repeating. Direction is from index `0` to index `N.length`. When last observable emits it starts at `0` again
- Observables can only emit once at a run: `0 - N.length`. Multiple emits are `distincted`

**FYI:** The code is actually pretty straight foward. It just looks big, as I added several comments to avoid confusion. If you have questions comment and I will try to answer.

```js
const { Subject, merge } = rxjs;
const { map, scan, distinctUntilChanged, filter } = rxjs.operators;

const source1$ = new Subject();
const source2$ = new Subject();

function toggleEmit(...observables) {
  // amount of all observables
  const amount = observables.length;
  
  // create your updating state that contains the last index and value
  const createState = (value, index) => ({ index, value });

  /*
  * This function updates your state at every emit
  * Keep in mind that updateState contains 3 functions:
  * 1. is called directly: updateState(index, amount)
  * 2. is called by the map operator: map(val => updateState(index, amount)(val)) -> Its just shorthand written
  * 3. is called by the scan operator: fn(state)
  */
  const updateState = (index, amount) => update => state =>
    // Check initial object for being empty and index 0
    Object.keys(state).length == 0 && index == 0
    // Check if new index is one higher
    || index == state.index + 1
    // Check if new index is at 0 and last was at end of observables
    || state.index == amount - 1 && index == 0
      ? createState(update, index)
      : state
  
  // Function is used to avoid same index emit twice
  const noDoubleEmit = (prev, curr) => prev.index == curr.index

  return merge(
    ...observables.map((observable, index) =>
      observable.pipe(map(updateState(index, amount)))
    )
  ).pipe(
    scan((state, fn) => fn(state), {}),
    filter(state => Object.keys(state).length != 0),
    distinctUntilChanged(noDoubleEmit),
    map(state => state.value),
  );
}

const result$ = toggleEmit(source1$, source2$);

result$.subscribe(console.log);

source2$.next(0);
source1$.next(1);
source2$.next(2);
source2$.next(3);
source1$.next(4);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are probably more elegant solutions to this, but I normally reach for [scan](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/scan) and create a [little state machine](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-61yy9a?file=index.ts):

```js
import { merge, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { scan, filter, map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

const left = new Subject<number>();
const right = new Subject<number>();
const example = merge(
  left.pipe(map(val => ({ tag: 'left', val }))),
  right.pipe(map(val => ({ tag: 'right', val })))
).pipe(
  scan<{ tag: string; val: number }, { previous: string; emit?: number }>(
    (acc, { tag, val }) => {
      if (acc.previous !== tag) {
        return { previous: tag, emit: val };
      }
      return { ...acc, emit: null };
    },
    {
      previous: 'right',
      emit: null
    }
  ),
  filter(x => x.emit !== null),
  map(x => x.emit)
);
console.clear();
const subscribe = example
  .pipe(take(10))
  .subscribe(val => console.log('output', val));

right.next(1);
left.next(2);
right.next(3);
left.next(4);
left.next(5);
right.next(6);
```

Comment: I checked your solution in stackblitz and filled it with sample emits (obs1 and obs2) in the following direction (obs2, obs1, obs2, obs2, obs1). It seems like your solution doesnt work for the required edge cases. If observable 2 emits initially the value goes through, although it shall start at obs 1. If one observable double emits (obs1 - obs2 - obs2 - obs1) then the obs2 value gets emitted although it should not.

Comment: @JonathanStellwag I've updated it so that obs1 (left in my example) will emit first. I'm not sure about your other point though. In my example left will emit five times as often as right and it gives me the result I expect. Is the confusion due to the log statements? It's only _output x_ that should be alternating, rather than _merged x_ which may be duplicated

Comment: I refer to this: "then ignore Observable1 and only wait for a value from Observable2". I tested this use case in Stackblitz and it did not work. The observable 1 emitted continuously.

Comment: @JonathanStellwag maybe you can post a link with your changes? I'm afraid I still can't find any issue with it

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-questions-67831376?file=index.js

Comment: I created you a stackblitz where I copied your pipe and pushed in some test emits. Your pipe might work for your specific interval example. If non replayed creation observables are handed over - your logic seems not to work as i receive (0,1,2,3,4)

Comment: By changing the values emitted you changed the behaviour of the scan function. I was using the strings "left" and "right" to discriminate between the different observables. I've edited your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-questions-67831376-rlramt?file=index.js) to correct it

Comment: Sorry! I didn't read you pipe detailed and made a mistake here. I see your solution now. Nevertheless your solution only works with fixed values. To work around you can create a state inside the scan that creates a tuple/object that holds the index of the observable and the value. Then your pipe could handle also dynamic values (not only left/right). But I have to appreciate that it works with your given values. Again - sorry I did not see this point.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like there are quite a few ways to solve this. Here's another with [expand](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-pkcamh?file=index.ts).

```js
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { expand, mapTo, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

const left = interval(1000).pipe(mapTo('left'));
const right = interval(5000).pipe(mapTo('right'));
const example = left.pipe(
  take(1),
  expand(x => (x === 'left' ? right : left).pipe(take(1)))
);
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

I'd be interested if someone has a way to do it with one of the `buffer*` operators

Answer (score 1):

Because it's Friday, I wrote an implementation of this.

This is javascript not typescript but you can see how I'm solving it.

```
function roundRobinMerge(...observables) {
  const indexedObservables = observables.map(
    (obs, index) =>
        obs.pipe(
            map(
               v => ({
                    index: index,
                    value: v
                })
          )
      )
  );
  let nextIndexToListenTo = 0;
  return merge(...indexedObservables)
    .pipe(
        filter(n => n.index === nextIndexToListenTo),
        tap(n => nextIndexToListenTo = (n.index + 1)%indexedObservables.length),
        map(n => n.value)
    );
}
```

To see this in action, go to https://rxviz.com, and copy and paste the code below

```
const { interval, merge } = Rx;
const { take, map, filter, tap, share } = RxOperators;

function roundRobinMerge(...observables) {
  const indexedObservables = observables.map(
    (obs, index) =>
        obs.pipe(
            map(
            v => ({
                    index: index,
                    value: v
                })
          )
      )
  );
  let nextIndexToListenTo = 0;
  return merge(...indexedObservables)
    .pipe(
        filter(n => n.index === nextIndexToListenTo),
        tap(n => nextIndexToListenTo = (n.index + 1)%indexedObservables.length),
        map(n => n.value)
    );
}

// Now to demonstrate it
function mapper(label) {
  let index = 0;
  return () => `${label}${++index}`;
};

const a = interval(750)
    .pipe(
        map(mapper('a')),
        take(10),
      share()
   );

const b = interval(1300)
   .pipe(
     map(mapper('b')),
     take(10),
     share()
   );


merge(
  [
    a,
    b,
    roundRobinMerge(a, b)
  ]
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably achieve what you want playing with Subjects.

Here a possible solution.

You start with the concept of creating some sort of *switch* that is triggered any time either `Observable1` or `Observable2` notify. Once the *switch* emits, than we `switchMap` to one of the source observables, i.e. `Observable1` and `Observable2`), we wait for it to notify and we `switchMap` to the other one, again we wait for it to notify and finally we `next` the switch to start all over again.

Looking at the code probably the logic is clearer.

```
// these are the 2 switches
const switch1 = new Subject<any>();
const switch2 = new Subject<any>();

// res1 and res2 are the Subjects that notify the results we want
const res1 = new Subject<any>();
const res2 = new Subject<any>();

// for each source Observable we create a pipe along the logic explained above
const switchToObs2 = switch1.pipe(
  switchMap(() =>
    observable1.pipe(first()).pipe(
      tap((v) => res1.next(v)),
      switchMap(() => observable2),
      tap((v) => switch1.next(v))
    )
  )
);
const switchToObs1 = switch2.pipe(
  switchMap(() =>
    observable2.pipe(first()).pipe(
      tap((v) => res2.next(v)),
      switchMap(() => observable1),
      tap((v) => switch2.next(v))
    )
  )
);

// we subscribe to the 2 pipes to activate the processing
merge(switchToObs2, switchToObs1).subscribe();

// we start the switches
switch1.next("start");
switch2.next("start");

// eventually we subscribe to the result
merge(res2, res1).subscribe(console.log);
```

[Here a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-nkbwbn?file=index.ts) with this solution

Answer (score 1):

You could put your sources in an array and use `switchMap` with a `BehaviorSubject`:

```js
const sources = [a$, b$];
const source$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

const emit$ = source$.pipe(
  switchMap(n => sources[n]),
  map((val, i) => {
    const nextIndex = (i+1) % sources.length;
    source$.next(nextIndex);
    return val;
  })
);
```

Breakdown:

- `source$` emits the index of the source you want to listen to
- `switchMap` subscribes to the source and emits its value
- `map` calls `source$.next()` to emit the next index, then simply returns the received value

Notice this works with 1 or more sources.

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-67831376?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100) demo.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another interesting (in my opinion anyway) example using `repeat`. Take a value from one observable, then take another value from the second observable, then repeat:

```js
import { concat, interval, of } from 'rxjs';
import { take, switchMap, repeat, mapTo } from 'rxjs/operators';

const left = interval(10000).pipe(mapTo('left'));
const right = interval(1000).pipe(mapTo('right'));

const example = left.pipe(
  take(1),
  switchMap(leftVal => concat(of(leftVal), right.pipe(take(1)))),
  repeat()
);
console.clear();
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log('output', val));
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rssqu6?file=index.ts)